# Java 7u7 setLookAndFeel doesn't work?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, compiler-errors

In Netbeans 7.2 when I type in `setLookAndFeel();` it says the method isn't found.  What did I do wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SalutonFrame extends JFrame  {

    public SalutonFrame() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        super("Saluton Mondo!");

        setLookAndFeel();

        setSize(350, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, note that `JFrame` itself is not a `JComponent`. It doesn't have a Look & Feel, except the one provided by the host platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the look and feel of a frame, you must do it before the constructor, via the UIManager. You can do it like so:

```
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    JFrame someFrame = new JFrame();
```

or whatever class your look and feel you want to use is instead of the basic Java look shown in the example. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

> ..the method isn't found.

Much like the method `getPonyRide()`.  If we make up methods that are not defined in the class or any class it extends, the compiler will advise that they do not exist.

IDEs will typically show a drop-down menu of choices if you type something like..

```
instanceOfObject.
```

..or..

```
this.
```

At the moment the `.` is typed (or several moments later, depending on the speed of the development box), a list of possible methods and attributes should appear.  Look carefully through the possibilities before choosing one.

### Recommendations

1. Don't extend frame, simply reference one.  Prefer [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).
2. Don't call `setSize()`, instead call `pack()` after all components are added.
3. Use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` for the exit operation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand your first recommendation. It seems like you're implying that making a class an instance of `JFrame` is bad. It's a lot less troublesome, for me at least, than having to refer to the frame over and over again.

Comment: @fireshadow52 If the frame has no custom methods, it should not be extended.  Another way to express that is "prefer [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)".  To lower the 'troublesome' factor, use an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were reading the book "Sams Teach Yourself Java in 24 Hours, 6th edition?

Anyway, you can do that this way:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SalutonFrame extends JFrame {

    public SalutonFrame() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        super("Saluton Mondo!");

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
            JFrame someFrame = new JFrame();

            setSize(350, 100);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        } 

        catch (Exception exc) {
            //  error handling
        }
    }
}
```

or you can do it this way:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SalutonFrame extends JFrame {

    public SalutonFrame() {

        super("Saluton Frame");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(350, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {

        try {        

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            //  error handling
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SalutonFrame sal = new SalutonFrame();
    }
}
```